# Multiple DB connection in R

Tags: mysql, r

I was wondering if someone could help with this annoying issue.
I'm trying to create/make multiple connections to different database. 
I have a data.frame with 3 connection credentials named **conf** - It works if I manually enter the connections variable like so:

```
conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user=conf$user, password=conf$passws, host=conf$host, dbname=conf$db)
```

which ends up creating a single connection.
However, what I want is to be able to refer to the connection as:

```
conf$conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user=conf$user, password=conf$passws, host=conf$host, dbname=conf$db)
```

here is the error message I'm getting.
Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'

I think the problem is how I'm adding **conf$conn**

Comment: You don't tell us anything about conf. That's kind of important here.

Comment: Is `conf` defined as a list? It's hard to replicate. This seems to work without error for me: `conf<-list(); conf$con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")`

Comment: @MrFlick Thank, I see you tried it on SQLite - I'm on MySQL... so not sure how that applies.

Comment: @HelenNeely It doesn't matter at all. It seems the issue is that you're trying to use a data.frame instead of a list for some reason.

Comment: What about `assign("conn1", con`)?

Comment: @Fernando I don't see the point of doing that.  There was never any issue assigning to a new variable.  The issue was when OP wanted to store inside a data.frame which doesn't really make sense.  The answer is simple: use a list instead.

Comment: Yes, if a list works, then it's the best solution. I tought `conn` was a special kind of object.

Comment: I probably didn't explain it well. I have a data.frame called conf - that has connection details for 3 databases, so that's where I'm referencing it like so conf$conn etc..

Comment: It seems to me like the more appropriate data structure for your needs would be a list.

Comment: If you have three rows, are you trying to assign them all the same connection with `conf$conn <- ...`? The implicit vectorization of turning that into three rows is what's causing the error message. You can probably explicitly `replicate()` that connection for the three rows, but really you should only store atomic data types in a data.frame. Better to use a list as already noted by Dason

Answer (score 2):

I used a combination of the [pool](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html) and [config](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/config/vignettes/introduction.html) package to solve a similar problem to set up a number of simultaneous PostgreSQL connections. Note that this solution needs a `config.yml` file with the connection properties for `db1` and `db2`.

```
library(pool)
library(RPostgreSQL)

connect <- function(cfg) {
  config <- config::get(config = cfg)
  dbPool(
    drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL", max.con = 100),
    dbname = config$dbname,
    host = config$host,
    port = config$port,
    user = config$user,
    password = config$password
  )
}
conn <- lapply(c("db1", "db2"), connect)
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips, will give it a go and let you know.